# .Net regex - extract data from one of two groups

Tags: .net, regex

Given two groups of data below and the limitation of .Net regex, no subtitution and no programmatic means, how can I capture data (Last Name or First Name) from the User Information group but not the Invoice Information group? When I construct a regex two results always occur.

```
User Information:
Title:                Product Specialist
Last Name:            Smithson
First Name:           Robert
Invoice Information: 
Title:                Buyer
Last Name:            Moneypenny
First Name:           Penelope
```

I can easily extract data from the Invoice group with this expression: `(?<=Invoice\sInformation\:(.*\r\n)*Last\sName\:\s*).*`, but the problem is the first group.

Comment: Could you please include the regex you've tried so far.

Comment: The data above is in a list each separated by CRLF, e.g. Last Name: Smithson on one line. Here is one of several regexes that extract two Last Names:

Comment: (?<=User\sInformation\:(.*\r\n)*Last\sName\:\s*).*

Comment: I can easily extract data from the Invoice group with this expression:
(?<=Invoice\sInformation\:(.*\r\n)*Last\sName\:\s*).* But the problem is the first group.

Comment: What do you mean by *capture* here? What are the expected results? Do you want to *match* the first/last names? Or is *capturing* like `User Information:\r\nTitle:.*\r\nLast Name:\s*(.*)\r\nFirst Name:\s+(.*)`enough? What tool are you using?

Comment: @cefeg: Or this for matching: `(?<=^User Information:.*(?:\n(?!Invoice Information:).*)*\n(?:First|Last) Name:\s+)\b.*`? (if the `User Information` is at the *line* start, use `Multiline` option, add `(?m)` at the pattern start).

Comment: You can try like this: [`(?ms)(?<=^User(?:(?!^Invoice).)*?Name:\s*)\S+`](http://www.regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3fms)(%3f%3c%3d%5eUser(%3f%3a(%3f!%5eInvoice).)*%3fName%3a%5cs*)%5cS%2b&i=User+Information%3a%0d%0aTitle%3a++++++++++++++++Product+Specialist%0d%0aLast+Name%3a++++++++++++Smithson%0d%0aFirst+Name%3a+++++++++++Robert%0d%0aInvoice+Information%3a+%0d%0aTitle%3a++++++++++++++++Buyer%0d%0aLast+Name%3a++++++++++++Moneypenny%0d%0aFirst+Name%3a+++++++++++Penelope)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Thanks for the above expression which works perfectly. I never thought of using the options. The list of data has 50+ lines in it in multiple groups. The objective is to capture/extract most of the data and place it into database columns/fields. The application being used, ccScan, can do that as long as I provide a proper regex. Currently it captures the first occurrence Last Name and and then over writes it with the second or third occurrence. Your solution prevents this. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: But which one should I post and explain? :) `(?m)(?<=^User Information:.*(?:\n(?!Invoice Information:).*)*\n(?:First|Last) Name:\s+)\b.*`?

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to this one:<br> `(?ms)(?<=^User(?:(?!^Invoice).)*?Name:\s*)\S+`

Comment: @bobblebubble Apologies. It was your suggestion that worked. I missed seeing your handle. That coupled with Wiktor's comments solved my problem. Thanks to both of you.

Comment: @cefeg great you got going, whichever helped (:

Comment: Hi All. i have my answer mentioned above. This case can be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work for you as it references the "invoice" section as a marker to know where to stop collecting for the first name field, and therefore expects that the invoice section follows the user section. I'm assuming you want to extract all of the information and not just that one field:

```
User Information:\s+Title:\s+(.*?)\s+Last Name:\s+(.*?)\s+First Name:\s+(.*?)\s+Invoice
```